# increase array in module

Tags: module, fortran

I am trying to write a small module/class in Fortran. The idea is very basic:

1. Create and initialize the object with a dedicated constructor
2. Add a new element inside of it

I already write Fortran but only subroutine and I will try to use oriented object principle. Currently I have two errors:

1. the constructor I built does not work (seems to not accept my input arguments)...
2. the `add_bb` procedure is not accepted.

*MNWE:*

```
   module test_mod
    implicit none

    type :: bb
       real :: item
       real,allocatable :: vect(:)
    end type bb

    interface bb
       procedure :: new_bb!,add_bb
    end interface bb

  contains

    type(bb) function new_bb(val,nbv)
      real, intent(in) :: val
      integer, intent(in) :: nbv
      integer :: ii

      new_bb%item=val
      allocate(new_bb%vect(nbv))

      print *,nbv
      do ii=1,nbv
        new_bb%vect(ii)=val
        print *,ii
      enddo

      print *,new_bb%vect
    end function new_bb

    type(bb)  function add_bb(it)
        real,intent(in) :: it
        integer :: sp
        real,allocatable :: tmp(:)

        sp=size(add_bb%vect)+1

        allocate(tmp(sp))
        tmp(1:sp-1) = add_bb%vect(1:sp-1)
        call move_alloc(tmp, add_bb%vect)
        add_bb%vect(sp)=it
    end function add_bb
  end module test_mod

  program test
    use test_mod
    implicit none

    type(bb) :: cc
    cc=bb(10,20)
    call cc%add_bb(10)

    print *,cc%item
    print *,cc%vect
    !
  end program test
```

Comment: You seem to be mistaking constructors with type-bound procedures.  `cc%add_bb` would be used for the latter.  I think we need a good idea of your level of knowledge before we can give you an answer you'd usefully understand.

Comment: In fact as you see my skill is low. But i was unable to find an useful tutorial to try to do what I want. I probably mixed bad things.

Comment: As you may note, I removed references to Fortran 90 from your question.  Much of this is specific to Fortran from 2003, so you may find a F2003 tutorial more use than an F90.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix the bugs in your code, but as I worked on it more, I discovered more and more fundamental flaws in your code. Obviously, that implies that you are likely not well familiar with OOP, in particular, in Fortran. Therefore, I recommend you to grab a book, for example, "Modern Fortran Explained" by Metcalf et al. and learn this topic. Meanwhile, here is a revised version of your code that at least works without syntax error:

```
   module test_mod
    implicit none

    type :: bb_type
       real :: item
       real, allocatable :: vect(:)
    contains
       procedure, pass :: add_bb
    end type bb_type

    interface bb_type
       procedure :: construct_bb
    end interface bb_type

  contains

    function construct_bb(val,nbv) result (bb)
      real, intent(in) :: val
      integer, intent(in) :: nbv
      type(bb_type) :: bb
      integer :: ii

      bb%item=val
      allocate(bb%vect(nbv))

      print *,nbv
      do ii=1,nbv
        bb%vect(ii)=val
        print *,ii
      enddo

      print *,bb%vect
    end function construct_bb

    subroutine add_bb(self,it)
        class(bb_type), intent(inout) :: self
        real,intent(in) :: it
        integer :: sp
        real, allocatable :: tmp(:)
        sp=size(self%vect)+1
        allocate(tmp(sp))
        !tmp(1:sp-1) = self%vect(1:sp-1)
        !call move_alloc(tmp, self%vect)
        !self%vect(sp)=it

end subroutine add_bb

  end module test_mod

  program test
    use test_mod
    implicit none

    type(bb_type) :: cc, dd
    cc=bb_type(10,[20])
    call dd%add_bb(10.0)

    print *,cc%item
    print *,cc%vect
    !
  end program test
```